# Is there any purpose to the three questions asked when making a new game?

Tags: final-fantasy-tactics-a2

After deciding a name for your character, you are then asked three questions: *this summer I'm going to*, *as a personal goal I want to*, and *next year I promise not to.* I assume these questions serve a purpose, but the game doesn't give any hint as to what it is, nor does the manual seem to contain any information.

Do these questions serve any purpose?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These questions determine the bonus clan privilege Clan Gully will start with. For example, choosing options A B A will grant you the bonus privilege **Bonus AP 1**.

The clan privlages you'll start with are:

- Power UP 1
- Agility UP 1
- Speed UP 1
- Luck 1
- *Bonus Privilege*

If the bonus privilege you choose is already possessed than you'll get an upgraded version of that privilege (i.e. taking Power Up 1 would grant you Power Up 2). The bonus privilege can be any of the following ([source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/937330-final-fantasy-tactics-a2-grimoire-of-the-rift/faqs/53627)):

- **Agility up 2:** Slightly improves chance to hit and avoid being hit.
- **Bonus AP 1:** Slightly increases the ability points awarded for completing a quest.
- **Bonus EXP 1**: Slightly increases the experience points awarded for completing a quest.
- **Bonus Gil 1:** Slightly increases the gil awarded for completing a quest.
- **Bonus CP 1:** Slightly increases the clan points awarded for completing a quest.
- **Luck up 2**: Slightly increases critical hit rate and chance of an Opportunity turn.
- **Power up 2:** Slightly increases damage dealt and reduces damage received.
- **Smash Gauge Bonus 1:** Slightly increases the rate at which the smash gauge is filled.
- **Speed up 2:** Slightly raises speed.

The chart below shows the bonus privilege earned for every possible question and answer combination for the Japanese version of the game (for example, A B B grants **Bonus CP 1**)([source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/937330-final-fantasy-tactics-a2-grimoire-of-the-rift/faqs/53627)):

> **Combo     Bonus**
>
> A A A   :  Bonus EXP 1
>   A A B   :  Bonus Gil 1
>   A A C   :  Luck up 2
>   A B A   :  Bonus AP 1
>   A B B   :  Bonus CP 1
>   A B C   :  Agility up 1
>   A C A   :  Speed up 2
>   A C B   :  Power up 2
>   A C C   :  Smash Gauge Bonus 1
>   B A A   :  Agility up 2
>   B A B   :  Luck up 2
>   B A C   :  Bonus Gil 1
>   B B A   :  Smash Gauge Bonus 1
>   B B B   :  Power up 2
>   B B C   :  Bonus CP 1
>   B C A   :  Speed up 2
>   B C B   :  Bonus EXP 1
>   B C C   :  Bonus AP 1
>   C A A   :  Bonus Gil 1
>   C A B   :  Luck up 2
>   C A C   :  Power up 2
>   C B A   :  Agility up 2
>   C B B   :  Bonus EXP 1
>   C B C   :  Speed up 2
>   C C A   :  Smash Gauge Bonus 1
>   C C B   :  Bonus CP 1
>   C C C   :  Bonus AP 1

Comment: It's a little unclear, but you should note that the bonus privilege adds (giving you Lv 2 instead of Lv 1) to the your current privilege if you already have it. (E.g. Power Up 1 + Power Up Bonus = Power Up 2). And the Clan Privilege "Clan Points +1" should be "Bonus CP 1"